# Проблемы при загрузке DataSet.Load

Tags: c#, ado.net

Добрый день. Пытаюсь загрузить данные полученные из базы через ADO.NET 3-rd компонент, у которого в DataReader нет метода DataReader.Fill.
Вот собственно код:

```
DataSet set = new DataSet(e.Node.Tag.ToString());
set.EnforceConstraints = false;
set.Load(reader, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, "");
```

И иногда, на некоторых таблицах со временем, начинает выпадать в исключения на методе DataSet.Load:

```
Exception.Message:

 Невозможно удалить этот столбец, т.к. он является частью ограничения Constraint38 для таблицы Table1.

Exception.StackTrace:

   в System.Data.DataColumnCollection.CanRemove(DataColumn column, Boolean fThrowException)
   в System.Data.DataColumnCollection.BaseRemove(DataColumn column)
   в System.Data.DataColumnCollection.Remove(DataColumn column)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.RollbackAddedItems(List`1 items)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.SetupSchemaWithKeyInfo(MissingMappingAction mappingAction, MissingSchemaAction schemaAction, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object chapterValue)
   в System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping..ctor(DataAdapter adapter, DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Boolean keyInfo, SchemaType schemaType, String sourceTableName, Boolean gettingData, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   в System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMappingInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   в System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillMapping(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 schemaCount, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   в System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   в System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   в System.Data.Common.LoadAdapter.FillFromReader(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   в System.Data.DataSet.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler, DataTable[] tables)
   в System.Data.DataSet.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, String[] tables)
```

Вроде как я отключил проверку на уникальность ключей, но все равно идет какая-то проверка на Constraints ключей и индексов.

---

Проблема оказалась в System.Data.DataKey - он имеет встроенное ограничения на 32 столбца, и выкидывает исключения если их больше(в моем случаи их 38).
Единственное решения этой проблемы, что я нашел - писать врапер для DataReader-е, и удалять все первичные и уникальные ключи, когда возвращаем их в DataReader.GetSchemaTable().

Comment: Накопите статистику, если отваливается скорее всего в настройках БД проблема

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем нашел место в System.Data где происходить исключения:

```
if (this.table.DataSet != null)
{
    ParentForeignKeyConstraintEnumerator parentForeignKeyConstraintEnumerator = new ParentForeignKeyConstraintEnumerator(this.table.DataSet, this.table);
    while (parentForeignKeyConstraintEnumerator.GetNext())
    {
        Constraint constraint = parentForeignKeyConstraintEnumerator.GetConstraint();
        if (!((ForeignKeyConstraint)constraint).ParentKey.ContainsColumn(column))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (fThrowException)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilder.CannotRemoveConstraint(constraint.ConstraintName, constraint.Table.TableName); // <===== вот тут выкидывается исключения
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Это какой-то внутренний баг фреймверка, они бы хотя бы проверили на `this.table.DataSet.EnforceConstraints != false` прежде чем выкидывать исключения.
Придется писать свой врапер для DataReader и при получении схемы через GetSchemaTable() чистить все Constraint.

Comment: Нет, это не баг фреймворка. `EnforceConstraints `- это настройка, которая относится к данным, а не к схеме.

Answer (score 0):

Настоящее исключение происходит где-то в блоке try, после чего перехватывается [в блоке catch](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/SchemaMapping.cs,972):

```
        try {
          // много кода
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (ADP.IsCatchableOrSecurityExceptionType(e)) {
                RollbackAddedItems(addedItems);
            }
            throw;
        }
```

К сожалению, в процессе обработки исключения возникает другое исключение, из-за чего исходное исключение теряется.

Имеет смысл [включить отладку системных библиотек](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx), после чего поставить точку останова внутрь этого блока catch и попытаться поймать ошибку.

Comment: Нет, исключения происходит именно в том месте, что я описал - они сами его выкидывают. Зачем то идет проверка Constraint-ов в DataSet и его таблицах.
За подсказку об отладке исключения в системных библиотеках - спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @DeusExMachine то место, которое описали вы, вызывается из RollbackAddedItems (см. стек).

Comment: Да, Вы правы, дошел до того места, что Вы описали, вот что в исключении там:

**"Число столбцов не может превышать 32."**

Наверно какие-то ограничения 3-rd ADO.NET компонента, надо будет смотреть.